# How to use generics of generics in java interfaces

Tags: java, generics, interface

I am trying to write a generic interface for my base service. Here is what I tried at all:

Assume that we have a request and response object. Each request type must be bound to a response type, so we can handle response types of requests.

```
abstract class Response {

}    

abstract class Request<R extends Response> {

}
```

Now let's write some implementations about them:

```
class DummyResponse extends Response {

}

class DummyRequest extends Request<DummyResponse> {

}
```

Okay, we have implementations. Let's dive into the interface, where I struggled:

```
interface MyService {

   <R extends Response, T extends Request<R>> R getResponse(T request);

}
```

When I implement this MyService, I've got errors:

```
class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {

    //these method gives me error
    @Override
    public DummyResponse getResponse(DummyRequest request) {
        //do sth
        return response;
    }

}
```

So why am I doing this? Because I want to write lots of service implementations with their own request and response objects, so I can handle them from one point -- the service interface.

How can I do this with using interfaces? Or is it a wrong approach? What is the true way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To implement the `MyService` interface correctly, you must provide a generic method `getResponse` that matches the type parameters.  However, you are implicitly placing type arguments `DummyResponse` and `DummyRequest`, and you aren't declaring type parameters `R` and `T` as `MyService`'s `getResponse` method does.

The solution here is to move the type parameters `R` and `T` to the interface itself.

```
interface MyService<R extends Response, T extends Request<R>> {
    R getResponse(T request);
}
```

Then `MyServiceImpl` can supply type arguments to `MyService` when implementing it, and `getResponse` can use those type arguments to successfully implement the `getResponse` method.

```
class MyServiceImpl implements MyService<DummyResponse, DummyRequest> {

    // This now implements MyService correctly. 
    @Override
    public DummyResponse getResponse(DummyRequest request) {
        //do sth
        return response;
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks for answer, i know i can do this but with this approach i have to use interface with generic definition. i want to use generics only in method level. MyService must be stay MyService, not MyService<Bla, Blabla>

Comment: Think about it up a level.  If an interface says that implementers have to provide a method that accepts any valid combination of R and T, how is it an implementation of that interface to make a class that only accepts one specific combination?  Java generics are not a templating tool, forget now that the syntax looks the same and you'll save yourself a lot of frustration.

Comment: @oko The problem is that if the generics must exist on the method in the interface, then all concrete classes must have generics on the implementing method.  All concrete classes would need to take any kind of `Response` and any kind of `Request` that associates with it.  The design of a generic method on the non-generic interface is incorrect here; the correct design is with a generic interface.